# Converting fields from String to Date in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

I'm trying to index emails into elasticsearch with logstash

My conf file is like this :

```
sudo bin/logstash -e 'input
{ imap 
{ host => "imap.googlemail.com" 
password => "********" 
user => "********@gmail.com" 
port => 993 
secure => "true" 
check_interval => 10 
folder => "Inbox" 
verify_cert => "false" } } 
output 
{ stdout 
{ codec => rubydebug } 
elasticsearch 
{ index => "emails" 
document_type => "email" 
hosts => "localhost:9200" } }'
```

The problem is that two fields of the outputs are parsed as String fields but they are supposed to be "date" fields

The format of the fields is as below :

```
"x-dbworld-deadline" => "31-Jul-2019"
"x-dbworld-start-date" => "18-Nov-2019"
```

How can I convert these two fields into date fields ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about create mapping of index on Elasticsearch.

It may look like this:

```
PUT date-test-191211
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "x-dbworld-deadline": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dd-MMM-yyyy"
        },
        "x-dbworld-start-date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dd-MMM-yyyy"
        }
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

Then, those fields are recognized as Date format:

result:
[[image: mappings.jpg]]